# Sorting Array Object in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to sort array according to values in it, My code is compiling but its not sorting

```
public void onResponse(TopScoreObject[] response) {
            try {
                if(response != null){
                    List<TopScoreObject> mList = arrayToListObject(response);
                    Collections.sort(mList, new Comparator<TopScoreObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(TopScoreObject topScoreObject, TopScoreObject t1) {
                            return topScoreObject.getUsername().compareTo(t1.getUsername());
                        }
                    });
                    Collections.reverse(mList);
                    mAdapter = new LadderBoardAdapter(mList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                } else{
                    DisplayMessage.displayErrorMessage(getActivity(), "No score found yet");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What you mean by "it is not sorting" ? What is your desired output and given input?

Comment: Provide sample input and output. Also look into using a debugger to follow it step by step.

Comment: Do you intend to sort by user name or by score?  Your example is attempting to sort by username.  As a simple starter, you could try Arrays.sort(response)

Comment: I am so sorry. Its working I just forgot to notice that I am also reversing the array

Answer (score 1):

You can try sorting username alphabetically in Java 8 using lambda this way, takes care of null values where username is null.

```
  public void onResponse(TopScoreObject[] response) {
    try {
      if(response != null){
        List<TopScoreObject> mList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(response));
        mList.sort(TopScoreObject::getUsername, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **response** is an array, try using `Arrays.sort(response)`
2. No need to convert **response** array to an Arraylist for sorting purpose
3. Remove `Collections.reverse(mList)` as you are already sorting it

Answer (score 0):

1. It would be easier and clearer if you made `TopScoreObject` implement `Comparable` and move the sorting rule into the class `TopScoreObject`. In this way, the code would be more cohesive and less coupled.
2. And don't forget to assign value after sorting the collection `response = sorted.toArray();`
3. And why not use the collection instead of the array?

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are sorting by your custom logic and then using default reverse of collection which damages your sorting.

> Collections.reverse(mList);`

You can add negation to your sorting logic and remove <strike>Collections.reverse(mList);</strike>

```
 List<TopScoreObject> mList = arrayToListObject(response);
                Collections.sort(mList, new Comparator<TopScoreObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(TopScoreObject topScoreObject, TopScoreObject t1) {
                        return !topScoreObject.getUsername().compareTo(t1.getUsername());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Using `reverse` doesn't "damage" the sorting, it just reverses it. The result is still sorted, just backwards.